# c# Unity. SetActive. Объект не включается после выключения

Tags: c#, unity3d

Мне нужно по нажатию клавиши включать и выключать объект, но после его выключения, по следующему нажатию, он не включается, хотя делаю всё, как в остальных гайдах. Также, если заранее выключить объект, то он не включается. Объект добавляю перетаскиванием.

Вот код:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Toggle_platform : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject platform;
    public bool toggle = true;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F))
        {
            toggle = !toggle;
            platform.SetActive(toggle);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Я не вижу никаких явных ошибок, но возможна ошибка в том, что вы отключаете ту GameObject, в котором закреплен этот код.

Comment: Скрипты на отключенном объекте не выполняются, объект не может сам себя включить.

Comment: Спасибо! не знал

Comment: Я тоже сталкивался с этой проблемой. Я просто через код отключал SpriteRender и другие компоненты.